# Merge Sort Function not working when size of vector is not 2^n

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, mergesort

I want to preface this question by saying I'm a beginner to c++.

For practice, I tried creating a merge sort function using the elementary knowledge that I have learnt. The code is as follows:

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

vector<int> mergesort(vector <int> x);
int main(){
    vector<int> tosort={1,9,0};
    tosort=mergesort(tosort);
    for(int  i=0; i<tosort.size(); i++){
        cout<<tosort[i]<<" ";
    }

}
vector<int> mergesort(vector <int> x){
   if (x.size()==1){
       return x ;
   }
   else{
       int vsize=x.size();
       vector<int> halfv1(x.begin(),x.begin()+ceil(vsize / 2));
       vector<int> halfv2(x.begin()+ceil(vsize / 2),x.end());
       
       
       halfv1=mergesort(halfv1);
       halfv2=mergesort(halfv2);
       int counter1=0;
       int counter2=0;
       while(counter1+counter2<vsize){
           if(counter1==ceil(vsize / 2)){
               for(int i=counter1+counter2;i<vsize;i++){
                   x[i]=halfv2[counter2];
                   counter2++;
               }


           }
           if(counter2==floor(vsize / 2)){
               for(int i=counter1+counter2;i<vsize;i++){
                   x[i]=halfv1[counter1];
                   counter1++;
               }

           }
           if(counter1 !=ceil(vsize / 2) && counter2 !=floor(vsize / 2)){
               if(halfv1[counter1 ]<=halfv2[counter2]){
                   x[counter1+counter2]=halfv1[counter1];
                   counter1++;
               }
               else{
                   x[counter1+counter2]=halfv2[counter2];
                   counter2++;
               }
           }
       }
       return x;
   }
}
```

The code works fine when the size of the vector tosort is 2^n. However, if it isn't then the output is erroneous. For example, in the above example the output is 0 1 0. Please can you help me identify the issue.

I have tried working through the logic line by line and there doesn't seem to be a mistake. I suspect there is an issue with regards to knowledge that I'm not aware of.

Please can you help me out considering I'm a beginner. Also I know there are probably more efficient ways to write the code but I just wanted to practice my algorithm skills with my current knowledge and find my gap in my understanding here.

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Have you tried to [*debug*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) the program?

Comment: On a different note, `vsize / 2` is a pure integer operation, with an integer result. Passing the result to the floating-point `ceil` function won't really do anything useful.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude yes I have read this document and followed the advice except using a debugger. Could you recommend where to learn how to use a debugger. I tried using one but couldn't understand the interface. Also, I'm using Xcode.

Comment: Side note :  `vector<int> halfv1`  means you are copying a lot of data. consider sorting in-place (e.g. use std::span<int> to make a view on half your data)

Comment: @PepijnKramer thank you very much for the advice. can you suggest any other ways to refine the program(that a beginner can understand)?

Comment: Note that Some programmer dude's second comment actually explains the issue you're seeing: you're expecting `counter2==floor(vsize / 2)` to be equivalent to `counter2 == vsize - ceil(vsize / 2)`, but in fact it's not, because `ceil(vsize / 2)` is *vsize* divided by two, rounded *down*.

Comment: Minor point: after `if (x.size() == 1) return x;` you don't need to write an `else` block; none of the remaining code will be executed if the code takes the early return. Removing the `else {` and the closing `}` will make the code easier to read. In particular, it will make it easer for me to see whether that final `return x;` is in the right place.

Comment: Side note: `#include "bits/stdc++.h"` loads the gun by including the tens of thousands of identifiers in The C++ Standard Library. `using namespace std;` Takes off the safety by pulling all of those identifiers into the global namespace where they will come into conflict with your code. This makes it very easy to shoot yourself in the foot, so be extremely cautious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The immediate issue is that the size of `halfv2` is not `floor(vsize / 2)` but `vsize - vsize / 2` (or `(vsize + 1) / 2)`), so you need to change all those comparisons to not access indexes out of bounds. (Note that `ceil` was only applied to the truncated result of `vsize / 2`.)

Consider comparing against the `size()` of the vectors instead.

In addition, [`std::merge`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/merge) provides the functionality you are trying to implement here.

Comment: I'm unable to understand. Suppose I had {0,1,9} like above then halfv1 would be {0,1} and halfv2 would be{9}. Then isn't the size of halfv2 floor(3/2)?

Comment: @Boson No, `halfv1` would actually be `{0}` and `halfv2` would be `{1, 9}` because `ceil(3 / 2)` is just `ceil(1)` as `3 / 2` is evaluated first (integer division).

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks a lot. It's working once I change  int vsize=x.size(); to double vsize=x.size().

Comment: @Boson Happy to help. You really don't need to take `ceil` at all though. Using `v.size() / 2` as the midpoint is the standard way of doing it.

Comment: Thanks once again. I love this place! I've been struggling with this for over an hour and here there are so many very smart people ready to help me in minutes! Would you recommend any other changes to the code besides the ones that have been mentioned already by you and others to make it more efficient(something that a beginner can understand)?

Comment: Also, to confirm you mean replacing ceil(vsize / 2) by vsize/2 and floor(vsize / 2) by vsize-vsize/2  so we can utilise the integer division?

Comment: @Boson I mean just use `vsize / 2` as the midpoint when creating the two halves. You can then directly compare with the `size()` of `halfv1` and `halfv2` instead of manually writing expressions for their sizes.

Comment: @Boson As for other recommendations, you can simplify the body of the while loop to a single if-else statement: `if (counter2 == halfv2.size() || counter1 < halfv1.size() && halfv1[counter1] <= halfv2[counter2]) x[counter1 + counter2] = halfv1[counter1], counter1++; else x[counter1 + counter2] = halfv2[counter2], counter2++;`